# While trying to render two template views in emberjs only the later one renders

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new to emberjs and I was trying to render two views using two different script tags in markup but only the later one gets rendered.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view Ember.Select
         contentBinding="App.peopleController"
         selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.person"
         optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
         optionValuePath="content.id"}}

  <p>Selected: {{App.selectedPersonController.person.fullName}}
    (ID: {{App.selectedPersonController.person.id}})</p>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view Ember.Checkbox}}
    Check me!
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

I have created the fiddle also for this here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgLCr/416/)

In this case I can only see the check box but can't see the drop-down select view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give a name for a template, a template without a name is considered a template for the ApplicationView, and i guess if you have several templates without a name ember choses the last one. So you must do something like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="check-box">
   {{#view Ember.Checkbox}}
     Check me!
   {{/view}}
</script>
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/zgLCr/419/ - wrapping Ember.Checkbox in another view doesn't make much sense, but it shows how you can name and render your views, although you can place checkbox right inside your ApplicationView's template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
   {{view Ember.Select
     contentBinding="App.peopleController"
     selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.person"
     optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
     optionValuePath="content.id"}}

   <p>Selected: {{App.selectedPersonController.person.fullName}}
      (ID: {{App.selectedPersonController.person.id}})</p>

   {{#view Ember.Checkbox}}
      Check me!
   {{/view}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but I wanted them in different views because I wanted to create a widget with a header, content and footer. All having different views for e.g. [jsfiddle for widget](http://jsfiddle.net/Zdr7W/1/). Do I have to add them all in an application view? because in that the mark up wont be that much readable. I there some way out for this?

Comment: That entirely depend on your application - if your header, content and footer are like widgets, that is they do some stuff beyond displaying static content and have they own controllers, then it might be good idea to split them up. By the way I would recommend reading this http://trek.github.com/ or looking at the code of simple todo-like application written using ember https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs to get the idea of router and outlets and how you can connect views depending on the state of your application.